# Python call function with getattr and args/kwargs from a string

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, getattr

I want to call a module function with `getattr` (or maybe something else?) from a string like this:

```py
import bar
funcStr = "myFunc(\"strParam\", 123, bar.myenum.val1, kwarg1=\"someString\", kwarg2=456, kwarg3=bar.myenum.val2)"
[function, args, kwargs] = someParsingFunction(funcStr)
# call module function
getattr(bar, function)(*args, **kwargs)
```

How can I extract the `args` and `kwargs` from the string, so I can pass them to `getattr`?
I tried a `literal_eval` approach with pythons `ast` module. But `ast` is not able to evaluate the enums of the module `bar`. And all other examples on SO pass a `kwargs` map with only strings in it. And they especially never parse the arguments from a string. Or is there another way to directly call the function from the string?

**EDIT:** A python script reads the function string from file. So using `eval` here is not advised.

**EDIT2:** Using python 3.6.3

**EDIT3:** Thanks to the first two answers I came up with two ideas. After parsing the `args` and `kwargs` out of the input string there are two possibilities for getting the right type of the arguments.

1. We could use `ast.literal_eval(<value of the argument>)`. For arguments with standard type like in `kwarg2` it will return the needed value. If this excepts, which will happen for the enums, then we we will use `getattr` on the `bar` module and get the enums. If this excepts as well, then the string is not valid.
2. We could use the `inspect` module and iterate through the parameters of `myFunc`. Then for every `arg` and `kwarg` we will check if the value is an instance of a `myFunc` parameter (type). If so, we will cast the arg/kwarg to the `myFunc` parameter type. Otherwise we raise an exception because the given arg/kwarg is not an instance of a `myFunc` parameter. This solution is more flexible than the first one.

Both solutions feel more like a workaround. First tests seem to work. I will post my results later here.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
funcStr = r"""myFunc(\"strParam\", 123, bar.myenum.val1, kwarg1=\"someString\", kwarg2=456, kwarg3=bar.myenum.val2)"""

def someParsingFunction(s):
    func, s1 = s.split('(', 1)
    l = s1.replace('\\','').strip(')').split(', ')
    arg_ = [x.strip('"') for x in l if '=' not in x]
    kwarg_ = {x.split('=')[0]:x.split('=')[-1] for x in l if '=' in x}
    return func, arg_, kwarg_

class bar:
    def myFunc(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(*args)
        print(kwargs)

[function, args, kwargs] = someParsingFunction(funcStr)
getattr(bar, function)(*args, **kwargs)

# 123 bar.myenum.val1
# {'kwarg1': '"someString"', 'kwarg2': '456', 'kwarg3': 'bar.myenum.val2'}
```

---

Alternatively

```
funcStr = r"""myFunc(\"strParam\", 123, bar.val1, kwarg1=\"someString\", kwarg2=456, kwarg3=bar.val2)"""

def someParsingFunction(s):
    func, s1 = s.split('(', 1)
    l = s1.replace('\\','').strip(')').split(', ')
    arg_ = [x.strip('"') for x in l if '=' not in x]
    kwarg_ = {x.split('=')[0]:x.split('=')[-1] for x in l if '=' in x}
    return func, arg_, kwarg_

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.val1 = '111'

[function, args, kwargs] = someParsingFunction(funcStr)

bar = Bar()
obj_name = 'bar' + '.'
args = [bar.__getattribute__(x.split(obj_name)[-1]) if x.startswith(obj_name) else x for x in args]

print(args)
```

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately this is the solution I started with and it does not work. As you can see all your ```kwargs``` values are of type string and they will not match the function signature types.

Comment: @stackomatiker Ah I think I better understand your problem now, how about the alternative I posted? It is  rather an idea than a full solution,

Comment: The expected result should be: ```args=["strParam", 123, bar.myenum.val1]``` and ```kwargs={kwarg1: "someString", kwarg2: 456, kwarg3: bar.val2}```.
Unfortunately this is not the case in your solution. But your solution gave me an idea. It is psossible to get the enum by splitting the input and execute ```val=getattr(bar.myenum, "val1")```. But this is not the solution for the other kwargs, like ```kwarg2```.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_bar_args(arg_str):
    """
        example:
        arg_str='bar.abc.def'
        assumess 'bar' module is imported
    """
    from functools import reduce
    reduce(getattr, arg_str.split('.')[1:], bar)

def parseFuncString(func_str):
    '''
        example: func_str = "myFunc(\"strParam\", 123, bar.myenum.val1, kwarg1=\"someString\", kwarg2=456, kwarg3=bar.myenum.val2)"
    '''
    import re
    all_args_str = re.search("(.*)\((.*)\)", func_str)
    all_args = all_args_str.group(2).split(',')
    all_args = [x.strip() for x in all_args]
    kwargs = {kw.group(1): kw.group(2) for x in all_args if (kw:=re.search('(^\w+)=(.*)$', x))}
    pargs = [x for x in all_args if not re.search('(^\w+)=(.*)$', x)]
    pargs = [get_bar_args(x) if x.startswith('bar.') else x for x in pargs]
    kwargs = {k: get_bar_args(v) if v.startswith('bar.') else v for k, v in kwargs.items()}
    print(f'{all_args=}\n{kwargs=}\n{pargs=}')
    func_name = func_str.split("(")[0]
    return func_name, pargs, kwargs
```

Comment: There is a little syntax error in the print statement and you used the Walrus operator which is not available in my python version (3.6.3). But I rewrote it and it was not a problem. The reduce with ```getattr``` works for the enums in bar. But the other parameters like ```123``` and ```kwarg2``` will be still returned as strings. And they won't match the ```myFunc``` signature. The expected result should be: ```args=["strParam", 123, bar.myenum.val1]``` and ```kwargs={kwarg1: "someString", kwarg2: 456, kwarg3: bar.myenum.val2}```.